# How to redeclare a pattern in a derivative class?

Tags: c++

I have a base class:

```
class BaseClass {
private:
    typedef void ( BaseClass::*FunctionPtr ) ( std::string );
    FunctionPtr funcPtr;
public:
    void setFunc( FunctionPtr funcPtr ) {
        this->funcPtr = funcPtr;
    }   
}
```

And now I need to create a derivative class:

```
class DerivativeClass: public BaseClass {
public:
    // I can overload the FunctionPtr here but for what?
    // then I also need to overload setFunc() function but I can't do it 
    // because I have too much code in a BaseClass which works with funcPtr.
    // I mean works with some function from this DerivativeClass.
    typedef void ( DerivativeClass::*FunctionPtr ) ( std::string );
    // therefore it has not any common sense in using BaseClass at all if I
    // will overload all its functions here.

    void callMe() {
        printf( "Ok!\n" );
    }
    void main() { // the program starts here
        setFunc( &DerivativeClass::callMe ); // here's my problem
    }
}
```

I have a problem there because setFunc() gets pointer to functions from BaseClass only but I need to set a pointer to DerivativeClass::callMe function. How can I solve this problem? Maybe there's some great solution using templates?

Comment: I suggest you read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) (and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)) instead, it will make such things easier.

Comment: `void main() { // the program starts here` -- really? This is not Java and OOP is just one of the paradigms supported by C++.

Comment: The function "main" in this example CANNOT be the start of the program, as it needs an object to be called with.

Comment: Sure I know it. I meant that the main() there is just the start point in that class nothing else :)

Comment: You should explain more of the real problem. Likely there is a better overall solution but you have not given us enough information to advise you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've found some cool solution for this problem. Look:

```
template < class T >
class BaseClass {
private:
    typedef void ( T::*FunctionPtr ) ();
    FunctionPtr funcPtr;
public:
    void setFunc( FunctionPtr funcPtr ) {
        this->funcPtr = funcPtr;
    }
};

class DerivativeClass: public BaseClass < DerivativeClass > {
public:
    void callMe() {
        printf( "Ok!\n" );
    }
    void main() { // the program starts here
        setFunc( &DerivativeClass::callMe );
    }   
};
```

If you have any suggestions on this - I highly appreciate it :)

Comment: Using a baseclass means that objects of multiple different types can be accessed by their common baseclass interface. By using a template this way, you define a baseclass for just this one type. Even if you have other classes using the same template, they will not have a common baseclass, you only save a bit of typing.